# SASS компилит не верный код в Css

Tags: gulp-sass

Есть вкл gulp, все работает компилится потом в любом элементе он начинает выкидывать ошибку и перечеркивать стили в сss. В чем может быть дело, была ли у кого такая проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
header__middle-title
   padding-top: 5%
   padding-top: 60%
   color: #fff
```

Это компилится в сss как `padding-top-color: #fff` соответственно происходит ошибка.

Comment: Появляется ли при этом в консоли ошибка? С помощью чего вы собираете проект и какие у вас настройки?

Comment: В одной строчке у вас табуляция с помощью таба, в другой, с помощью пробелов. Возможно у вас стоит настройка смарт табс? Сделайте табуляцию одинаковой везде, возможно это смущает компилятор

Comment: Andrey, спасибо ! 
Да, все было дело в табуляции через пробел color был задан.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее у вас стоит какой-то плагин типа `gulp-csso` который неверно компилирует стили. Проверьте `gulpfile.js` и вы найдете там что-то подобное в таске компиляции стилей.

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичная ситуация. Скопировал папку с виртуалки и делаю по ней другой сайт, немного меняя HTML и CSS. И получается что в SASS файлы не дает ничего дописать через табуляцию, из-за этого ошибка как у ТС.

Ошибок в консоли нет.

НО, если открыть файл SASS к примеру в Notepad, добавить что нужно, сохранить, а потом открыть в Sublime text и скомпилить, то все отлично работает. Проблема в Sublime text? Где искать?

---

И спустя 2 минуты решение, справа внизу в Саблайме - Конверт ту табс. :)